# Python: Nested While loop doesn't loop multiple times

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-loops

The function of my code is to paste coordinates all over the pdf as for my main project some pdf's aren't getting text pasted correctly so I am making code to try and debug the problem.

The part of my code that doesn't work is my nested while loop. It loops and starts the next loop, the second while loops 72 times as intended, however it doesn't add 50 and never loops again. I look at other nested while loop codes and I can't identify my problem.

Here is my code

```
 while count <= 612:  # width of pdf

        while count2 <= 792:  # height of pdf
            can.drawString(count, count2, str(count) + " " + str(count2))
            count2 += incremental_Value

        count += 50
```

There is no crash and changing "count" in the can.drawString() function moves the column of text over. So I know the issue is that the first while loop doesn't loop

Comment: You don't reset the value of `count2`, so the inner loop can't be entered on the second iteration of the outer loop. Maybe you want *one* loop that increments both variables each iteration until either condition is false?

Comment: damn that's not a mistake I have done in a while thx mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @chepner suggested, the inner loop doesn't get executed a second time because `count2` remains at its max value. To fix this you simply need to reset it before making the inner loop start again (so in the outer loop before the inner one), something like:

```
while count <= 612:  # width of pdf
    
    count2 = 0 # fix
    while count2 <= 792:  # height of pdf
        can.drawString(count, count2, str(count) + " " + str(count2))
        count2 += incremental_Value

    count += 50
```